# Calling functions between different classes

Tags: c#

I am used to writing embedded c and poorly skilled in c#.

My problem is that I want to be able to run the function `openAnotherForm()` from `Welcome_Form` and right now the code does not work. I patiently tried different things but only managed to push my frustration.

I simplified my relevant code to illustrate the problem.

File 1 - This will run and open file 2.

```
class UIcode
{
    private Welcome_Form Welcome;
    private AnotherForm_Form AnotherForm;

    public UIcode()
    {
        Welcome = new Welcome_Form();
        Application.Run(Welcome);
    }

    public void openAnotherForm()
    {
        Welcome.Hide();
        AnotherForm = new AnotherForm_Form();
        AnotherForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

File 2 - When I click `TheButton`, the program should run the function `openAnotherFrom` from file 1.

```
public partial class Welcome_Form : Form
{
    public Welcome_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TheButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Function from file 1
        UIcode.openAnotherForm();
    }
}
```

I realize the problem might be quite trivial but I would still be grateful for an explanation on how to do this.

Preferable: The functions from UIcode should only be recognized by classes specified by UIcode.

Comment: `openAnotherForm` is an instance method on UICode which means you will need to have an instance of that type to run it on. Alternatively you would have to make the method static which means it wouldn't be able to refer to any instance variables or methods on UICode which in this case would require refactoring or just wouldn't work.

Comment: Your second form is going to need a reference to the parent that opened it. You could pass it in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the constructor to take a reference to the instance of `UIcode` that opened it:

```
    private static UIcode myParent;

    public Welcome_Form(UIcode parent)
    {
        myParent = parent;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Now in UIcode:

```
   public UIcode()
   {
        Welcome = new Welcome_Form(this);
        Application.Run(Welcome);
   }
```

And finally, back in `Welcome_Form`:

```
    private void TheButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Function from file 1
        myParent.openAnotherForm();
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly the idea I was hoping for and also similar to what I tried already. However, I get an error on `public Welcome_Form(UIcode parent)`

Comment: @user3064934: What error? One note, you need to mark `UIcode` as a public class.

Comment: YES, that did it!! Thank you soo much :) Now I have the structure for most of my application.

Comment: On a side note, the error was: _Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'MyTool.GUI.UIcode' is less accessible than method 'MyTool.GUI.Welcome_Form(MyTool.GUI.UIcode)'_ But it was fixed when I change UIcode to public class

Comment: @AskMøller: Good. That error message is a little more cryptic that it needs to be, but it boils down to "you can't pass an instance of a private class to a public method"

Answer (score 0):

Your `openAnotherForm()` method is not `static`, so it needs an instance reference in order to be used. Either instantiate a UICode object, or mark the method as `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You to create an instance of the class in `File1` to call the method. You've called the class `UICode`, so the constructor should be renamed from `public UserInterface()` to `public UICode()`.

```
class UIcode
{
    private Welcome_Form Welcome;
    private AnotherForm_Form AnotherForm;

    public UIcode() // Renamed Constructor
    {
        Welcome = new Welcome_Form();
        Application.Run(Welcome);
    }

    public void openAnotherForm()
    {
        Welcome.Hide();
        AnotherForm = new AnotherForm_Form();
        AnotherForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public partial class Welcome_Form : Form
{
    public Welcome_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TheButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance UICode
        UICode instance = new UICode();

        // Call the method from the instance, not from the class.
        instance.openAnotherForm();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make `openAnotherForm()` a `static` method, but you'll also need to make the instance variables (`Welcome` and `AnotherForm`) `static`. You will also need to initialize them, but you can do that by making the constructor `static` as well.

```
class UIcode
{
    private static Welcome_Form Welcome;
    private static AnotherForm_Form AnotherForm;

    public static UIcode() // Renamed Constructor
    {
        Welcome = new Welcome_Form();
        Application.Run(Welcome);
    }

    public static void openAnotherForm()
    {
        Welcome.Hide();
        AnotherForm = new AnotherForm_Form();
        AnotherForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3064934: as elnigno said, that's because it references instance members. One question, is there any reason why all of `UIcode` not static? One solution would be to just do that.